# Upgrade from Fedora 8: no package fedora-upgrade available

Tags: linux, upgrade, fedora

I'm trying to upgrade my `Fedora 8`, by using `yum`, with the instructions given on [this page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum) and on [this page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_from_EOL_Fedora_using_yum#Fedora_8_-.3E_Fedora_9).

However, when I try to do `sudo yum install fedora-upgrade`, I get this error message:

`no package fedora-upgrade available`

How do I proceed?

Comment: A yum upgrade from Fedora 8 to anything released in the past few years is not recommended.

Comment: Maybe, but I need to do it. How do I?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I get the feeling the OP might've misinterpreted your comment perhaps. I assume you're advising that if they wish to upgrade they should take a different route (other than yum).

Comment: For something that old you want to reinstall from scratch. Otherwise, prepare to lose a month going one version at a time.